# Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, `style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}}` when using JSX.

./src/List.js :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './styles.css';


export default class BlogDetail extends Component{
    render(){
        return(

        <div>

        <section class="blog-details-hero spad set-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-image">
              <div class="hero-text">
                <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
                <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>

        )
    }
}
```

./src/styles.css :

```
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("http://3.128.190.113/media/cardekho-blog/blog-4.jpg");
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `style` prop to an object and camelCased properties:

```
<h1 style={{fontSize: `50px`}}>I am John Doe</h1>
```

See [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) in React docs.

> The `style` attribute accepts **a JavaScript object** with camelCased properties ***rather than*** a CSS string.

Answer (score 0):

As denoted by the error message, the style attribute needs to as per the spec. Refer [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) for more info.

This should fix your problem anyways -

```
<h1 style={{fontSize: '50px'}}>I am John Doe</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is so simple you used this :

```
<h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1
```

> Use this :

```
<h1 style={{font-size:"50px"}}>I am John Doe</h1>
```

Comment: `font-size` should be `fontSize`